# WPF custom MultiSelector won't use ItemTemplateSelector (but will use ItemTemplate)

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol, itemselector

I've searched for and found many questions similar mine but none of them seem to be quite my situation.  Admittedly, mine is something of an edge-case.  I'm hoping someone can spot what I'm missing here.

I've long been using a custom ItemsControl which derives from MultiSelector.  I have a custom DataTemplate to draw the items in it.  And they're drawn just fine if  ***and only if*** I use the ItemTemplate property on the control.

But when I try instead to the ItemTemplateSelector property, my override of SelectTemplate is not being called.   I've verified that it's creates and then set as the control's ItemTemplateSelector.  But the breakpoint for its SelectTemplate override never gets hit.

The net effect is that the nice shapes that were previously being drawn beautifully by my one and only DataTemplate now just show up as string names.

The view I'm using is like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Shapes.ShapeCanvas"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:gcs="clr-namespace:MyApp.Shapes"
             xmlns:gcp="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"
             xmlns:net="http://schemas.mycompany.com/mobile/net"
             >

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp.Core;component/Resources/Styles/ShapeItemStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- 
            Default data template for most ShapeVm types, custom data type for PolyLineVm 
            I've removed the contents for brevity but they draw Paths objects normally
            -->

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ShapeTemplate" DataType="{x:Type gcs:ShapeVm}"/>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="PolylineTemplate" DataType="{x:Type gcs:PolyLineVm}"/>

            <!-- ShapeTemplateSelector to pick the right one -->
            <gcs:ShapeTemplateSelector x:Key="ShapeTemplateSelector"
                                       DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource ShapeTemplate}"
                                       PolyLineTemplate="{StaticResource PolylineTemplate}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Canvas x:Name="Scene">
        <gcs:ShapesControl x:Name="ShapesControl"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                           ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShapeItemStyle}"
                           ItemsSource="{Binding Shapes}"
                           ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ShapeTemplateSelector}"
        >
            <!-- If I use this line instead of ItemContainerStyle, It *does* pick up shape template -->
            <!-- ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShapeTemplate}" -->

            <gcs:ShapesControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Transparent" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </gcs:ShapesControl.ItemsPanel>

        </gcs:ShapesControl>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Custom DataTemplateSelector

```
public class ShapeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        *** THIS NEVER EVEN GETS CALLED ***
        return item is PolyLineVm ? PolyLineTemplate : DefaultTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate PolyLineTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Custom MultiSelector ("ShapesControl")

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyApp.Shapes
{
    // Created By: 
    // Date: 2017-08-25

    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
    using System.Windows.Input;


    /// <summary>
    /// ShapesControl - our own version of a WPF MultiSelector.  Basically an
    /// ItemsControl that can select multiple items at once.  We need this to
    /// handle user manipulation of shapes on the ShapeCanvas and, potentially,
    /// elsewhere.
    /// </summary>
    public class ShapesControl : MultiSelector
    {
        protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
        {
            return (item is ShapeItem);
        }

        protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
        {
            // Each item we display is wrapped in our own container: ShapeItem
            // This override is how we enable that.

            return new ShapeItem();
        }

        // ...Other handlers are multi-selection overrides and removed for clarity
    }
}
```

Finally, the ShapeItemStyle I use to draw my custom ShapeItems

```
<Style x:Key="ShapeItemStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type gcs:ShapeItem}"
       d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type gcs:ShapeVm}}"
           >
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Left, Mode=OneWay}"/>
  <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Top, Mode=OneWay}"/>


  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type gcs:ShapeItem}">
        <Grid>
          >
          <!-- ContentPresenter for the ShapeVm that this ShapeItem contains -->

          <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Shape"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                            ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.RenderTransformOrigin}"/>
        </Grid>

      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

(Edit to add ShapeItem per request.  Note that this includes selection code that interacts with the  custom MultiSelector ("ShapesControl") above.  I removed some of those functions from ShapesControl code for brevity as they're triggered by mouse-clicks and I couldn't see how they could possibly prevent a custom DataTemplateSelector from being invoked.  But I've posted all of ShapeItem here)

```
namespace MyApp.Shapes
{
    [TemplatePart(Name="PART_Shape", Type=typeof(ContentPresenter))]
    public class ShapeItem : ContentControl
    {
        public ShapeVm ShapeVm => DataContext as ShapeVm;
        public ShapeType ShapeType => ShapeVm?.ShapeType ?? ShapeType.None;
        static ShapeItem()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata
                (typeof(ShapeItem), 
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ShapeItem)));
        }
        private bool WasSelectedWhenManipulationStarted { get; set; }

        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
            ParentSelector?.NotifyItemClicked(this, true);
            e.Handled = true;

        }

        // The following ShapeItem manipulation handlers only handle the case of
        // moving the shape as a whole across the canvas.  These handlers do NOT
        // handle the case of resizing the shape.  Those handlers are on the
        // ShapeHandleThumb class.

        protected override void OnManipulationStarting(ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            // The Canvas defines the coordinates for manipulation

            e.ManipulationContainer = this.FindVisualParent<Canvas>();
            base.OnManipulationStarting(e);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        protected override void OnManipulationStarted(ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(e.ManipulationContainer is Canvas);
            base.OnManipulationStarted(e);

            // If this item was selected already, this manipulation might be a 
            // move.  In that case, wait until we're done with the manipulation
            // before deciding whether to notify the control.

            if (IsSelected)
                WasSelectedWhenManipulationStarted = true;
            else
                ParentSelector.NotifyItemClicked(this, false);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        protected override void OnManipulationDelta(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(e.ManipulationContainer is Canvas);
            base.OnManipulationDelta(e);
            ParentSelector.NotifyItemMoved(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        protected override void OnManipulationCompleted(ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.Assert(e.ManipulationContainer is Canvas);
            base.OnManipulationCompleted(e);
            if (WasSelectedWhenManipulationStarted)
            {
                // If nothing moved appreciably, unselect everything.  This is how I
                // am detecting just a Tap.  I have to think there is a better way...

                var t = e.TotalManipulation.Translation;
                if (Math.Abs(t.X) < 0.0001 && Math.Abs(t.Y) < 0.0001)
                    ParentSelector.NotifyItemClicked(this, false);

            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private bool IsControlKeyPressed => 
            (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control;

        internal ShapesControl ParentSelector =>
            ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(this) as ShapesControl;

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(
                ParentSelector.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(this), 
                ShapeVm));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = 
            Selector.IsSelectedProperty.AddOwner(
                typeof(ShapeItem), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSelectedChanged));

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                var value = GetValue(IsSelectedProperty);
                return value != null && (bool)value;
            }
            set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value); }
        }
        private static void OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(target is ShapeItem item))
                return;

            var evt = (bool)e.NewValue ? Selector.SelectedEvent : Selector.UnselectedEvent;
            item.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(evt, item));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for `ShapeItem`?

Comment: I posted it at the bottom.  Thanks for actually taking the time to plough through all of this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with following code:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    // Each item we display is wrapped in our own container: ShapeItem
    // This override is how we enable that.

    return new ShapeItem();
}
```

When you override `GetContainerForItemOverride` method, it is your code's responsibility to use `ItemTemplateSelector` and attach it to ItemsControl.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I thought I had googled everything on writing a custom MultiSelector but I never knew this.  However I must admit I'm still at a bit of a loss.  I have no idea how WPF uses an ItemTemplateSelector under the hood.  I don't understand how I would go about doing what you recommend.

Comment: Do I call the Selector and set the result to be the ShapeItem's ContentTemplate?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Set the ShapeItem's ContentTemplateSelector to be the ItemTemplateSelector that the parent had.  Also I was missing a TemplateBinding in my ShapeItemStyle for ContentTemplateSelector (only had one for ContentTemplate).  I cannot begin to thank you enough for this.  I'd give you a hundred upvotes if I could.  To be able to go through all that code that somebody else wrote and spot such an obscure problem like that so quickly.  Incredible.